# Calendar Base Extension Template

Tags: calendar, typo3, radix, cal

I am new to TYPO3 and I'd like to change the way the extension "Calendar Base (cal)" outputs an event.
I would like to change the HTML-Output.

Where can I do this in the current version of Calendar Base and TYPO3 8.5.1?

And how can I select different templates for the same view?
I want to choose between two HTML-Outputs for e.g. the list view.

Can anybody please help me?

Greeting!
Malte

Answer (score 0):

Templates are located in EXT:cal/Resources/Private/Templates/v1/

Copy the ones, you want to change to a place somewhere in fileadmin/... Then change the copied templates as you need it.

Change the path to the template in TypoScript constants. For example:

```
plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.list.listTemplate = fileadmin/Templates/Html/ExtCal/list.tmpl
```

For different list views use a condition in TypoScript constants for another list template. For example:

```
[PIDinRootline = 40]
    plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.list.listTemplate = fileadmin/Templates/Html/ExtCal/list_aktuell.tmpl
[GLOBAL]
```